# How to write combinations of English words and Greek letters in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tex

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([tau for tau in range(365)])
y = np.random.normal(0,1, 365)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel(r"$\tau$")
plt.show()
```

I want to use both Greek letters and regular English words in my plot title and axis labels, but I can't find in the [reference](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/mathtext.html) of `matplotlib` how to write the combination of them. For example, how can I write **Lag: \tau**?

Comment: Does `plt.xlabel(r"Lag: $\tau$")` not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/mathtext.html):

> Any text element can use math text. You should use raw strings (precede the quotes with an 'r'), and surround the math text with dollar signs ($), as in TeX. Regular text and mathtext can be interleaved within the same string.

Therefore,

```
plt.xlabel(r"Lag: $\tau$")
```

should provide the result you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I'm only asking because "Lags:" would look a bit funny this way. Thought there might be a better solution. But this works. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use algebraic sum between strings. In this case your code becomes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([tau for tau in range(365)])
y = np.random.normal(0,1, 365)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('Lag: ' + r'$\tau$')
plt.show()
```

This trick is really useful also if you want to put superscripts and/or subscripts to greek letters or latin letters